# CakePHP join only the latest entry

Tags: cakephp, join

I have 2 tables :

```
ORDERS
------
id
type

LOGS
----
id
order_id
time
```

I want to query with cakephp so I have :

```
array(
    'Order' => array(
        'id' => '38',
        'type' => 'online',
    ),
    'Log' => array(
        'time' => '2014-09-24 21:17:14'
    )
)
```

The problem is that I want only the last order, not all orders with all logs.

I did something like this :

```
$ordersList = $this->Order->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Order.*',
        'Log.time'
     ),
     'joins' => array(
         array(
             'table' => 'logs',
             'alias' => 'Log',
             'type'  => 'right',
             'conditions' => array(
                 'Log.order_id = Order.id'
             ),
         )
     ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have only the last one, you can `order` the result by `log.time` and then take only the first record (with the param `'first'` or just by fetching the first record of the recordset).

For example :

```
$order = $this->Order->find('first', array(
    'order' => array('Log.time' => 'desc')
));
```

in your case :

```
$ordersList = $this->Order->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Order.*',
        'Log.time'
     ),
     'joins' => array(
         array(
             'table' => 'logs',
             'alias' => 'Log',
             'type'  => 'right',
             'conditions' => array(
                 'Log.order_id = Order.id'
             ),
             'order' => array('Log.time' => 'desc')
         )
     ),
);
```

As information, if you want to have a simple method to join  the models, take a look at the `containable` behavior. With this behavior, the link are setted in the model then you only have to declare which associated model you want to retrieve with your current model. 
=> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html